# Navigate to page on contact creation

Tags: visualforce, contact

I need to navigate to a custom VisualForce page after a user creates a contact.

The page needs to take the contact Id as I'll be using it associate the contact with an opportunity and an account.

How do I listen to the contact creation event so I can redirect to the page or is there a better way to accomplish this?

I was considering using a javascript button to call the navigations but then I have no idea how I would fire the account creation.

Comment: Are you using the standard layout for `Contact` creation or did you create a visualforce page for it ?

Comment: Standard layout